# Two priorities in a condition in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement

I did a simple game that generates a random number and the player needs to guess the random number. The player only has 6 chances to guess and the game will be over if the player didn't get to guess the number in that 6 chances. The problem is when the player enters the **RIGHT** answer on the **6th chance**. The system shows the `imgLose` even though the answer is **TRUE**.

Here is the code segment:

```
            guessCount += 1
            when {
                guessNumber > randomNumber -> {
                    status.text = "Less than ${tGuess.text}"
                    tGuess.text = ""
                }
                guessNumber < randomNumber -> {
                    status.text = "More than ${tGuess.text}"
                    tGuess.text = ""
                }
                guessNumber == randomNumber -> {
                    status.text = "You're Correct! \nThe Answer is ${randomNumber.toString()}"
                    btnGuess.isEnabled = false
                    imgWin.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    var soundEffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wining)
                    soundEffect.start();
                }
            }

            if (guessCount == guessLimit){
                status.text = "The Limit is Exceeded! \nThe Answer is $randomNumber"
                btnGuess.isEnabled = false
                var soundEffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.losing)
                soundEffect.start();
                imgLose.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
```

[The result with coding right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8n96.png)

Comment: change to if(guessCount > guessLImit)

Comment: You need to modify the if(guessCount == guessLimit) condition to manage the 6th chance

Comment: if i change if(guessCount > guessLimit) it will make guessCount upto 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's many ways to handle this, but also depends on the rest of your code.

If possible you could try to simply `return` after a correct guess, if there's no other relevant code in that function.

another way is to save in a boolean whether there was a correct guess and check on that. like this for example:

```
        var isCorrect = false
        guessCount += 1
        when {
            guessNumber > randomNumber -> {
                status.text = "Less than ${tGuess.text}"
                tGuess.text = ""
            }
            guessNumber < randomNumber -> {
                status.text = "More than ${tGuess.text}"
                tGuess.text = ""
            }
            guessNumber == randomNumber -> {
                status.text = "You're Correct! \nThe Answer is  ${randomNumber.toString()}"
                btnGuess.isEnabled = false
                imgWin.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                var soundEffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wining)
                soundEffect.start();
                isCorrect = true
            }
        }

        if (guessCount == guessLimit && !isCorrect){
            status.text = "The Limit is Exceeded! \nThe Answer is $randomNumber"
            btnGuess.isEnabled = false
            var soundEffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.losing)
            soundEffect.start();
            imgLose.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
```

and actually just changing this line should be enough, since it's only disabled on a right guess:

```
if (guessCount == guessLimit && btnGuess.isEnabled){
```

Comment: I somehow cannot think this way. Thanks its working now :) Im still new in programming